# How to call an external API then return this data from an in hapi.js Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, hapi.js

I am new to the Hapi.js node extension.

I am trying to call an external API into my server because the external API is protected with CORS and I can't call it from my front (Angular 9).

So I set up my hapi server with routes etc and now in a route I am trying to import the external data and when the front call the route of my hapi api it show the data from the external API.

I didn't find any documentation or already topics about this problem, if you could provide me with some information it would be very helpful!

*(I want to do my external API call from the route solcast)*

This is my **index.js** :

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config()
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');

const init = async () => {

    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost',
        routes: {
            cors: true
        }
    });

    server.route(require('./routes/base').test);
    server.route(require('./routes/solcast').solcast);

    await server.start();

    console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

This is my **solcast.js** :

This while console.log the error :

```
Error: handler method did not return a value, a promise, or throw an error
```

And then console.log the data. I assume that the data is not received when the return is done.

```
const joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");



exports.solcast = {

    method: 'GET',
    path: '/solcasttest',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        fetch("https://linkToTheExternalApi")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        console.log(testSolcast)

    }

}
```

Thank you for your help, if you need any other information hit me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error thrown suggests, a `handler` in `hapi.js` must return a value, a promise or throw an error.

In your case, the `handler` is an asynchronous operation, so you have to return a promise.

As `fetch` already creates a promise, it is enough if you return the promise created by `fetch` in your handler :

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

exports.solcast = {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/solcasttest',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        return fetch("https://linkToTheExternalApi")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                return data
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```