# Consuming external API from Hapi js server on startup not returning a promise

Tags: javascript, rest, handler, hapi.js, node-fetch

I am new to Hapi and I want to consume an API when the server starts up. I on start-up I am getting "Error: handler method did not return a value, a promise, or throw an error."

I came across this post and was trying to model my code after the answer supplied here, but it is not working, even though I am returning the promise from the fetch.

Here is my server.js.

```
"use strict";

var Hapi = require("@hapi/hapi");
var Request = require("request");
const Inert = require("@hapi/inert");
const Vision = require("@hapi/vision");

//Init server
const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: "localhost",
    routes: {
      cors: true,
    },
  });

  await server.register(Vision);
  await server.register(Inert);
  // await server.register(require("vision"));

  server.route(require("./routes/getapis").getapis);

  await server.start();

  console.log(`Server is running on ${server.info.uri}`);
};

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

This is my getApis.js

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const spendingApiUrl = `https://opendata.maryland.gov/resource/gja3-vy5r.json?$select=vendor_zip,sum(amount)&$where=vendor_zip between '20601' and '21930'&$group=vendor_zip&$order=sum_amount DESC`;
const numberOfTopZips = 3;
let results = [];
let marylandData = [];

exports.getApis = {
  method: "GET",
  path: "/getapis",
  handler: (request, h) => {
    return fetch(spendingApiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        marylandData = data;
        console.log(marylandData);

        //rateLimitedRequests(topZips(marylandData, numberOfTopZips));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  },
};
```

Comment: This is the post I mentioned that I was following that I mentioned above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234397/how-to-call-an-external-api-then-return-this-data-from-an-in-hapi-js-api

Comment: You're exporting `getApis` but calling `getapis` in the server? Additionally, what you're trying to achieve won't work like this anyway. The `handler` of `/getapis` will only be called when a client hits the API - it won't be called on load. For this you should create a [plugin](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/plugins).